# Intel Wireless card wakes up laptop every 15-45 minutes during sleep, logs telemetry, and goes back to sleep DESPITE being expressly told NOT to do so

Tags: wireless-networking, sleep, event-log, intel-core-i7, wake-up

I have a Razer Blade 15 (2019), with Intel i7-9750H and NVIDIA 2060. The wireless adapter is an Intel Wireless-AC 9560 at 160MHz. The laptop also has a Realtek PCE GbE Ethernet controller

Throughout the night, during sleep mode, my PC wakes up and my event viewer logs the following messages, then goes back to sleep after 3 minutes (as per my settings):

7025 - Dump after return from D3 before cmd
7026 - Dump after return from D3 after cmd
7021 - Connection telemetry fields and analysis usage
6062 - Lso was triggered

[Event Viewer Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnUm7.png)
[Event Viewer Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSz2W.png)
(the Kernel-Power and Power-Troubleshooter messages are the boilerplate "System has resumed from sleep" messages)

I receive these messages, in this order, every 23 minutes throughout the night while my laptop sleeps. They are all sourced from netwtw08, which the details panel shows as the driver for the Intel wireless card.

[Event Viewer Details Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rB5qX.png)

I have read every article on the front page of google for each of these events, as well as various forms of the title of this post. In accordance with all the guides and abysmally unhelpful Intel customer service I have seen, I have uninstalled the Intel drivers and reinstalled them multiple times. I have uninstalled the Intel drivers and installed the Razer-provided drivers. I have used the default Windows drivers. Nothing has changed.

In the device manager, I have disabled the ability to wake the computer for EVERY device except the keyboard and the system itself. My `powercfg /devicequery wake_armed` confirms this. The problem persists.

[Device Manager Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4PsV.png)
[Powercfg Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9XvM.png)

Just to prove that powercfg WOULD show the wireless chip if it was wake_armed, here's a screenshot of powercfg recognizing it:

[Powercfg Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2J8M6.png)

I don't have a screenshot on hand because I woke my PC with the lid just now, but when `powercfg /lastwake` doesn't show "Power Button or Lid", it says "Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz". Will update if I can snag one.

I have installed the Intel Bluetooth drivers to no avail. I have uninstalled them as well, to see if it changed anything. It did not.

Before you link me to any other threads: I've already read them. The vast majority consist of advice I have already tried (powercfg, Device Manager, update/reinstall/uninstall drivers) OR some unhelpful Intel representative going through a copy-pasted help guide only to suggest a clean Windows install. I shouldn't have to blast my PC in order to make Intel's drivers work, and I have no confidence that a clean install will work because this problem has existed since the day I first powered this laptop on earlier this year.

The worst part is, nobody even has an explanation as to what these messages MEAN or what function they serve. I can guess that the first 3 are related to Intel collecting data, but WHY ON EARTH does it have to SEND THAT DATA TO INTEL EVERY 15 MINUTES? And what the hell does "Lso was triggered" mean? I've seen countless forums complaining about the event being tied to dropped connection, but what does LSO stand for? and WHY is it triggering constantly through the night?

When I pay for a piece of hardware, I don't expect it to work right away. But I DO expect it to be able to function properly with some tweaking and I DO expect there to be information on how to set it up properly and I DO expect there to be documentation as to what the messages it produces are telling me.

I'll probably also post this on the intel forums, and on the very slim chance that someone from Intel manages to help me, I will repost the answer here on superuser.

UPDATE: it turns out the timing of the wake is synced with my "Hibernate after" settings. Windows wakes up from sleep in order to go into hibernation, but the Intel card does some telemetry and cancels the hibernate. 3 minutes later, the PC sleeps, and 20 minutes later the cycle continues. This despite the Intel card being disallowed to manage the PC's power state.

I am still looking for a way to disable the Intel telemetry in order to let my PC hibernate properly.

Comment: When you tried to reinstall drivers, did you use Intel's drivers or the ones from Razer's site?

Comment: @SamForbis post ssays "I have uninstalled the Intel drivers and reinstalled them multiple times. I have uninstalled the Intel drivers and installed the Razer-provided drivers. I have used the default Windows drivers." So yes, I tried both

Comment: Are you sure that you are not using the Intel "InstantGo (Connected Standby)" mode? In such a mode the regular wake-up would be by design.

Comment: @Robert AFAIK, I am not. I don't see an option for it in any settings, and my `powercfg /availablesleepstates` does not show it. I discovered that the regular wake up was caused by the system waking from sleep in order to hibernate, but the hibernate is somehow canceled (I still suspect the Intel card). Because the system woke, the intel card does its telemetry.

Answer (score 2):

I was having similar spamming-level volumes of EventVwr IDs 7025 & 7026 (up to 4,250 errors/day) on a Lenovo Yoga Slim 7i Pro, Windows 11 Pro 22H2, Intel 6E AX211 160MHz card. The spamming volumes of error messages were triggered only when the laptop was charging.
I solved this issue (reducing volume of messages down to an acceptable 250/day) by taking both of the following steps:

1. within Control Panel > Power Options > Change plan settings > Change advanced power settings > Sleep > Allow wake timers > Plugged In - change to Disable. On battery was already Disabled.
2. within Edit Group Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Power management > Sleep Settings there are two mentions of "Allow network connectivity during connected standby". Change both of these from Not Configured to Disabled. For those of you running Windows 11 Home, you will have to find the similar setting within the Registry.

I have not detected any adverse system behaviour from running with these settings. In particular, the machine still wakes up in the middle of the night to do Windows Updates, which is desirable.

Answer (score 0):

You could try searching POWER in Settings and find Power & Sleep. At the bottom of this page, change the Network Connection into Always. This seems like work for me.